# how to split findall result which contain "," in data

Tags: python

```
x = re.findall(r'FROM\s(.*?\s)(WHERE|INNER|OUTER|JOIN|GROUP,data,re.DOTALL)
```

I am using above expression to parse oracle sql query and get the result. 
I get multiple matches and want to print them each line by line.
How can i do that.
Some result even have "," in between them.

Comment: What are the results you are getting? What is the string you are matching?

Comment: `for result in x: print(result)`

Comment: Can you give input and expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
for elt in x:
    print('\n'.join(elt.split(',')))
```

`join` returns a list of the comma-separated elements, which are then joined again with `\n` (new line). Therefore, you get one result per line.

Comment: Problem is if i have "," in data itself.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to keep those commas?

Answer (score 0):

Your result is returned in a list.
from https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html:

> re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0) Return all non-overlapping
>   matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings.

If you are not familiar with data structures, more information [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html)
you should be able to easily iterate on over the returned list with a for loop:

```
for matchedString in x:
    #replace commas
    n = matchedString.replace(',','') #to replace commas 
    #add to new list or print, do something, any other logic
    print n
```